# LTSpice simulation stalls after 100ms transient with 'Heightened Def Con'

Tags: simulation, ltspice, pll

I simulate a system of two mutually delay-coupled electronic clocks (DPLLs - digital phase-locked loops). This worked well and also in reasonable time so far. However, moving into a particular regime of the parameter space of the individual DPLLs, i.e., very low cut-off frequencies of the loop filters (fc=14Hz) compared to the free-running frequency of about 1kHz for the LTC6900 VCOs at a high coupling strengths causes problems. The transient simulation runs fast for about 100ms and then suddenly stalls with convergence problems of the solver (excerpt, full log-file below):

> Heightened Def Con from 2.31358e-012 ++++++++++++to 2.3174e-012
>
> Heightened Def Con from 0.0100466 to 0.0100466

I tried different solvers and limits, however I could not solve the problem.

This is the state at which the simulation stalls:
[image]

This is the schematic I am simulating

[image]

This is a link to the netlist:
[link to netlist (dropbox)](https://www.dropbox.com/s/14mqe3emecankd5/netlist?dl=0)
This is a link to the spice-log file:
[link to spice-log (dropbox)](https://www.dropbox.com/s/hpyjfwlh217bifz/2LTC6900_1kHz_varTau.log?dl=0)

Specifically my questions are:
What besides changing the solver parameters can I do to solve the problem?
How can I find out more easily on which calculation the solver gets stuck?
Did I miss something in the schematic that could cause the stalling?

Comment: Plenty of "cheats" available! Have you tried the Alternative solver? Injecting 1 mohm resistors in critical nodes?

Comment: I use the 'alternate' solver and the 'modified trap' integration method. How do I determine which are the critical nodes?

Comment: @cuichi nodes with very high rates of change can cause trouble (any switch turning on at that time?). Sometimes adding a small capacitor (pFs) to a node also helps.

Comment: On top of what @Arsenal said, if you see any node jump up to MV range for ns or lower, a Mohm resistor to ground usually helps. In general, try to "bootstrap" yourself using ideal components first, like your OP, and then change gradually to real models. This way you can find where the problem lies.

Comment: Also try setting eeeever so slightly different delay times for the gates. For example `Td=2n` for `A1` and `Td=2.01n` for `A2`. Maybe also `Td=1.99n` for one of the XOR games. BTW, you can eliminate `Rmeas` and `C1` and set `Rout` and `Cout` inside the gate. There is no need to ground the gates since their 8th pin (the ground pin) is internally connected to `0` node (ground) unless otherwise specified. It's not a big deal, but it eliminates a bit the clutter. Also, try adding `Rser` and/or `Cpar` to the supplies, something like `1m`, both.

Comment: @Arsenal: there are no switches turning on at that time. actually the dynamics seem not to change that much anymore at that time. 
I know that the integration time of the RC filter is really large compared to the other time-scales. However, this is exactly what I need. Looks like as if I have to delete elements and to find out where the problem has its roots.

Answer (score 2):

Many thanks towards all the people who contributed their comments, thank you @winny, @Arsenal, and @a concerned citizen!

The simulation runs and does not stall anymore after making these changes:

1. added `.option cshunt=1e-15 reltol=0.003 abstol=1e-10 gmin=1e-10`, see [LTwiki](http://ltwiki.org/index.php?title=Convergence_problems%3F)
2. making XOR, d-flip-flop, and delays sightly heterogeneous

Before I had only made changes to `reltol` and `abstol` which did not suffice.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Have you tried without the `.option` part? Only the delays and, if needed, add a small `tau=X` to the gates, e.g. `1n`. That should make the rising/falling edges smooth and convergence friendly. Do note, however, that it can only be either `Rout/Cout`, or `tau`, or `trise/tfall` at one time. `Rout/Cout` is just `tau`, but with control over `Rout/Cout` (otherwise `Rout=1`), and `trise/tfall` will make the edges straight (trapezoidal), rising or falling.

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen I did try it with only using the heterogeneity, however that did not suffice. Also I have to admit that I am not sure that I introduced what you proposed. Do you mean `Rout DIVIDED BY Cout` with `Rout/Cout`, or do just `Rout OR Cout`.

Comment: I meant them as two terms (poorly written), `Rout` and `Cout`. Since you don't have output loading that should matter, it's safe to use `tau` (time constant), instead. That considers `Rout=1` and `Cout=tau/Rout=tau`.

Comment: I only have delays assigned to the XOR-operations, the d-flip-flops and of course the feedback and coupling connections. The operational amplifiers have no delay assigned. I hope that answers the question.